# How to set picture box height in percentage?

Tags: c#

I have a tablelayout panel and it has 3 rows first row is 70 percent and remaining 2 is 15 percent each.
in the first row i put a picture box and i dock it top but i want it's height to be the height of the row i put in.

I am trying it like this but it takes the height in int. And instead of 70% it accepts 70.
So how can i set it's height in percent.

```
public CtrlBasketItems()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pictureBox1.Height = (int)(tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[0].Height);
}
```

Comment: use the height of the panel and `* 0.7`

Comment: So you want your first row in the tablelayout to be 70% the height of the tablelayout and your picture box to be the same height as that 1st row (100% height of the row, 70% height of the tablelayout)?

Comment: @noelicus i want it's height to be increased as items that i am to draw on it that increases, so i want height like that.

Comment: Could we have an example? I still don't understand what you're after (your comments seem to contradict your question!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pictureBox1.Height = (int)(tableLayoutPanel1.Height * 0.7)
```

Then you would have to position it in the row as needed, of course

Comment: I set it dock top, how should i position it.

Comment: If you want it to be at the top but 70% of the height then no more is needed, it will position itself. I thought you might want it to be positioned in the middle row...

Comment: I am to loop items and draw on this picture box and need to set the height at run time of picture box, i am concerned if it crosses the maximum height then how can i increase the height?

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet *"if it crosses the maximum height"* the maximum height of what? It cannot be more than the maximum height of the panel it is contained by since it is taking 70% that height

Comment: If i have a  collection of item that i am draw on it, if the item collection height exceed the picture box maximum height, i woun't get an scroll there?

Answer (score 1):

Set your PictureBox to be `Dock = Fill` instead: your picture box will fill the cell it occupies (i.e. be the same height as the cell/row).

Comment: IF i dock fill then if item i am to draw on it they increases in height then how can i increase the height of this picture box.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand this comment. Your question asks how to make your picture box the height of the row? Setting it to fill will make it the height of the row - as the row changes height so will your picture box.